# Large number of Unicode characters not rendering correctly in a kivy TextInput

Tags: python, kivy, python-unicode

Question: How can I get all Unicode characters to render correctly in a TextInput using Kivy?

### More details below

I'm generating random Unicode characters in a range between 0x0200 and 0x9990 which is massive the issue is that a large portion of the characters will not render correctly in a TextInput to be more specific less than half will work.

Whatever doesn't render ends up looking like a small rectangle with an x through it, yet when I copy and paste it into another display source it works fine. I've run the code through idle and it displays fine as well the issue seems to be with kivy, any suggestions as to why this is happening?

---

```
import random
import kivy
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

kivy.require('1.9.1')

class testclass(object):

    def example(self, event):
        k_len = list()
        complete = ''
        for i in range(32):
            k_len.append(random.randint(0x0200, 0x9990))
        for i in k_len:
            if i != 32:
                complete += chr(i)
        result.text = complete

t = testclass()



Root = Widget(size = (600, 200))
buttonOne = Button(text = 'click me', pos = (1,170), size = (120,30))
buttonOne.bind(on_press = t.example)


result = TextInput(hint_text = 'Output: ', size = (600, 50), pos = (0, 0), multiline = (True))

Root.add_widget(buttonOne)
Root.add_widget(result)



class testappApp(App):
    def build(self):
       return Root


Window.size = (600, 200) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testappApp().run()
```

This code will only work if you have kivy setup, you can tweak it to work in idle but as I stated the code works as intended it's just not displaying correctly within kivy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your font does not seem to support these characters - switch to another one with support for that range (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block for more info on what needs to be there)

Comment: Gotcha that's what I figured I was just hoping I could be lazy or rather that the kivy team would just throw the necessary support in, thanks for the help.